# How to provide some component for dynamically created component injector? Angular Material, ComponentPortal

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have some component (SomeComponent). By clicking some button I create popup. I create it via ComponentPortal. Also, I create overlay and I attach portal to this overlay.

Here is the code:

```
const calendarPortal = new ComponentPortal(MyPopupComponent);
const positionStrategy = this.getPositionStrategy(this.getAnchorElement());
const overlayConfig = new OverlayConfig({
  positionStrategy,
  panelClass: 'popup'
});
this.popupRef = this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);
const calendarPopupComponent = this.popupRef.attach(calendarPortal);
```

Is it possible to somehow get SomeComponent instance?

I tried it through DI and got no success.

```
constructor(someComponentRef: SomeComponent) {
  ...
}
```

I have this at start of my app:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for MyPopupComponent: (?).
            Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyPopupComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:45245:17)
```

By the way, I get this on start of my app. Not when I try to create popup. Thats strange.

I found injector & viewContainerRef inputs in ComponentPortal. I tried both, but it didn't work.

So I need some way to get instance of SomeComponent inside MyPopupComponent. How can I handle this?

Here is the [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-jbguw3).

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example on stackblitz?

Comment: Can't you send custom data when opening a modal? The DI won't work because it's not upwards in the DI tree. It knows about the MyPopupComponent but give you the instance you want. You just need to pass `this` somehow.

Comment: @yurzui I added the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-jbguw3).

Comment: I don't need to send custom data. At some moment I want to toggle popup inside of popup. Method `toggle` is implemented in the parent component. And I want to access this method.

Comment: You have circular dependency

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ndsxva?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: So this error is caused by circ dep? Can you add the answer? I will approve it.

Comment: `Can't resolve all parameters for MyPopupComponent: (?)` is caused by circ dep, `No provider for AppComponent!` this happens when we didn't provide correct injector like `new ComponentPortal(PopupComponent, null, this.inj)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That perfectly worked.

Comment: All these stackblitzs are broken.

Comment: @Stephane You need to provide injector as 3rd argument into the ComponentPortal. Example: `const portal = new ComponentPortal(PopupComponent, null, <injector here>);`. You can pass current injector `this.injector`, but don't forget to get it through the DI system: `constructor(private injector: Injector) {}`

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Yes I have added the injector as 3rd argument. Now I wonder how to use some Angular Material stuff, like say, an icon <mat-icon> for example, in the dynamic component.